# C# Is it thread safe to subscribe Same event handler for all Objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling, thread-safety

I have a situation in my project where i have connect to multiple server and listen for events. Whenever a event received from the server, Handler should add the event to the common queue for processing.  All  connections should add received events to the queue.

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
        Connection c = new connection(item);

         c.start();
         c.EventReceived+=new EventHandler(myHandler);
         list.add(c);
}

protected void  myHandler(eventArgs)
{
     //add it to the concurrent queue
}
```

Here i doubt that whether it can be able to handle those events without any threading issues.  Please let me know if you have any patterns or built in APIs to handle this safely.

Comment: You are getting this very wrong.  It is "list" that is not thread safe.  Subscribing the event is not the problem since the object is new.  Locking is required is prevent any code for accessing the list while you are adding objects to it.  Be careful here, threading is going to eat you alive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thread-safety always needs a context - a *from what*.

## If you mean the +=

For the `+=`, that depends on how the event is implemented. If it is implemented as a field-like event, i.e.

```
public event SomeEventType EventReceived;
```

then yes: it is thread-safe. The specification requires that the accessors for field-like events are thread-safe, although the implementation can vary (for example, the MS compiler used to use `lock(this)` or `lock(typeof(DeclaringType))`, however it now uses `Interlocked` instead).

If the event is implemented manually, i.e.

```
public event SomeEventType EventReceived {
    add { ... }
    remove { ... }
}
```

Then the thread-safety is defined entirely by the `add`/`remove` implementations.

## If you mean the invoke

Then that is thread-safe since delegates are immutable, but note that it all happens on the single thread that invokes the thread. However, a common mistake is to introduce a race condition in a `null` test:

```
if(EventReceived != null) EventReceived(this, someArgs);
```

The above is *not* thread-safe, since technically the value of `EventReceived` can change after the test. To ensure this does not error, it should be:

```
var handler = EventReceived;
if(handler != null) handler(this, someArgs);
```

## If you mean the handlers

Then the thread-safety is defined entirely by the individual handlers. For example, in UI applications it is the handlers that must check for, and switch to, the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!. i have event declared like a field so it is thread safe. I think Handler Calls will be synchronous. Is there any way to make handler called simultaneously?

Comment: @Jajesh if you mean concurrently: sure - use GetInvocationList to expand into individual delegates, and invoke them separately on workers

Answer (score 3):

**Quoting from C# spec**

```
When compiling a field-like event, the compiler automatically creates 
storage to hold the delegate, and creates accessors for the event that 
add or remove event handlers to the delegate field. In order to be thread-safe, 
the addition or removal operations are done while holding the lock (§8.12)
on the containing object for an instance event, or the type object (§7.6.10.6)
for a static event.
```

Bottom line is if the `EventReceived` is field like event(non custom implementation) then its thread safe!

**Update**
Current implementation uses Interlocked for thread safety

[image]

Comment: Actually, that isn't the current specification - it does not use `lock` any more (and indeed, the ECMA specification has always made it clear that any thread-safe implementation is valid)

Comment: I believe the spec has been updated and newer one uses Interlocked as verified from reflector just now. Thanks for correcting!