# Is there a thread-safe way to copy a decorated object's event handlers?

Tags: c#, events, thread-safety, decorator

I'm writing a C# class that decorates an object that can raise events. The decorator can instantiate a new decorated object and swap the old one out in response to an asynchronous event that occurs on any consuming thread. In initializing the new decorated object, I need to add all of the event handlers from the old decorated object to the new decorated object and continue to add/remove handlers from both objects until the swap occurs. Is there an existing common solution to this problem?

This is a conceptual example of what's going on:

```
interface IFoo
{
    event Action Barred;

    void Bar();
}

class BasicFoo : IFoo
{
    public event Action Barred;
    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Barring");
        Barred?.Invoke();
    }
}

class DecoratedFoo : IFoo
{
    private IFoo _Decorated;

    public DecoratedFoo()
    {
        _Decorated = new BasicFoo();
    }

    public event Action Barred
    {
        add => _Decorated.Barred += value;
        remove => _Decorated.Barred -= value;
    }

    public void Bar() => _Decorated.Bar();

    public void SwapDecoratedFoo()
    {
        // Can occur at any time from any thread.

        var newFoo = new BasicFoo();

        /* 
         * How to reassign events from _Decorated to newFoo, and in a way
         * that's thread safe while _Decorated.Barred may still be adding
         * or removing handlers while the swap is occurring?
         */

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Decorated, newFoo);
    }
}
```

Comment: The assingment can be done in class code. While external code can only add and remove Event handlers - via the (hidden) add/remove function/property like constructs - the class code has full access to the backing variable, including assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to have your own event in the Decorated wrapper and invoke it when the wrapped (Basic) object's event fires. You will also need another kind of locking other than Interlocked, because Interlocked is not enough to group together multiple statements. You can use SemaphoreSlim(1,1) to do it, like this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    event Action Barred;
    void Bar();
}

class BasicFoo : IFoo
{
    public event Action Barred;
    public void Bar() { … }
}

class DecoratedFoo : IFoo
{
    public DecoratedFoo(IFoo foo = null) => this.Decorated = foo;
    public event Action Barred;

    public void Bar()
    {
        try {
            this._lock.Wait();
            this._decorated?.Bar();
        } finally {
            this._lock.Release();
        }
    }
    private SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public IFoo Decorated {
        get {
            try {
                this._lock.Wait();
                return this._decorated;
            } finally {
                this._lock.Release();
            }
        }
        set {
            try {
                this._lock.Wait();
                if (this._decorated != null) {
                    this._decorated.Barred -= this.OnDecoratedBarred;
                }
                this._decorated = value;
                if (this._decorated != null) {
                    this._decorated.Barred += this.OnDecoratedBarred;
                }
            } finally {
                this._lock.Release();
            }
        }
    }
    private IFoo _decorated = null;

    private void OnDecoratedBarred() => this.Barred?.Invoke();
}
```

One comment about this, the design assumes that IFoo.Bar() does not call back into user code. If it does, then there is a pretty high chance of deadlock if/when that user code calls DecoratedFoo.Bar(). In that situation you should make the design asynchronous to prevent deadlock.

Use of this.Barred seems to be thread-safe, see [C# Is it thread safe to subscribe Same event handler for all Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534462/c-sharp-is-it-thread-safe-to-subscribe-same-event-handler-for-all-objects) . Also since the event handlers are invoked sequentially there is not much risk that the event handlers will interfere with each other (at least not directly).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid locking on every request to Bar() (or every event invocation) since this needs to be particularly performant. Something that introduces thread contention is a non-starter unfortunately. Though I think this approach to tracking the events combined with a read-writer lock may be enough. I'll give that a shot and if I confirm it works I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: The usage of Interlocked was only intended to make a thread-safe swap, not for a full lock.

Comment: If you want to allow multiple tasks to call the decorated Bar() then you really have no choice but to use a lock. Having said that, Semaphore Slim is pretty lightweight.

Comment: One defect of the design I put above is that it leaves the wrapped IFoo exposed. The problem with that is it means another caller could call its Bar() method without locking, which would be unsafe of there are also calls coming in through the decorator. A better design would have the BasicFoo privately owned and allocated by the decorator. To deal with the need to have a variety of derived classes you could pass in a factory, Func<IFoo>, to the constructor.